# Importing into a SQL Server database

Tags: python, sql-server

I initially started this to import into a NoSQL database which works fine, but couldn't find the correct tools for report writing. So I'm switching to SQL Server so I can use SSRS. But I'm having issues importing the data into tables in my SQL Server database

```
importncdrdata = "INSERT INTO ncdr.dbo.ncdrdatatest (Hospital, YrQTRid, MetricKey, LineText, Year, Quarter, YrQtrRange, qtrnum, qtrden, qtrpercent, subgroup) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"
importvolgroup = "INSERT INTO ncdr.dbo.ncdrvoltest (Hospital, YrQTRid, MetricKey, LineText, Year, Quarter, YrQtrRange, rqtrnum, rqtrden, rqtrpercent, volnum, volpercent, subgroup) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"

def importncdrfile():
        # Open the workbook and select the first worksheet
        wb = xlrd.open_workbook(self.filename)
        sh = wb.sheet_by_index(1)
        # Function to import main set of data
        if yearqtrid.get() == "2019Q3":
            def excelToDict(hospital, metricKey, lineText, year, quarter, yrQtrRange, num, den, percent):
                for rownum in range(12, sh.nrows):
                    ncdr = OrderedDict()
                    row_values = sh.row_values(rownum)
                    ncdr['Hospital'] = hospitalchosen.get()
                    ncdr['YrQTRid'] = yearqtrid.get()
                    ncdr['MetricKey'] = row_values[metricKey]
                    ncdr['LineText'] = row_values[lineText]
                    ncdr['Year'] = year
                    ncdr['Quarter'] = quarter
                    ncdr['YrQtrRange'] = yrQtrRange
                    ncdr['qtrnum'] = row_values[num]
                    ncdr['qtrden'] = row_values[den]
                    ncdr['qtrpercent'] = row_values[percent]
                    ncdr['SubGroup'] = 'holder'
                    ncdr_list.append(ncdr)

            # List to hold dictionaries
            ncdr_list = []
            # Imports data into MongoDB takes the aboce code and then runs the function against each set of data and then repeats for all 4 Quarters
            excelToDict(n,0, 1, 2018, 4, 20184, 2, 4, 6)
            excelToDict(n,0, 1, 2019, 1, 20191, 8, 10, 12)
            excelToDict(n,0, 1, 2019, 2, 20192, 14, 16, 18)
            excelToDict(n,0, 1, 2019, 3, 20193, 20, 22, 24)
            cursor.executemany(importncdrdata, ncdr_list)
            #x = importncdrdata.insert_many(ncdr_list)
            # function to import volume group and rolling quarters
            def excelToDictvol(hospital, metricKey, lineText, year, quarter, yrQtrRange, rqtrnum, rqtrden, rqtrpercent, volnum, volpercent):
                for rownum in range(12, sh.nrows):
                    ncdrvol = OrderedDict()
                    row_values = sh.row_values(rownum)
                    ncdrvol['Hospital'] = hospitalchosen.get()
                    ncdrvol['YrQTRid'] = yearqtrid.get()
                    ncdrvol['MetricKey'] = row_values[metricKey]
                    ncdrvol['LineText'] = row_values[lineText]
                    ncdrvol['Year'] = year
                    ncdrvol['Quarter'] = quarter
                    ncdrvol['YrQtrRange'] = yrQtrRange
                    ncdrvol['rqtrnum'] = row_values[rqtrnum]
                    ncdrvol['rqtrden'] = row_values[rqtrden]
                    ncdrvol['rqtrpercent'] = row_values[rqtrpercent]
                    ncdrvol['volnum'] = row_values[volnum]
                    ncdrvol['volpercent'] = row_values[volpercent]
                    ncdrvol['SubGroup'] = 'holder'
                    ncdr_vollist.append(ncdrvol)

            ncdr_vollist = []
            excelToDictvol(n,0, 1, 2019, 3, 20193, 26, 28, 30, 32, 34)
            #v = importvolgroup.insert_many(ncdr_vollist)
            cursor.executemany(importvolgroup, ncdr_vollist)
```

The error I am getting is

> TypeError: ('Params must be in a list, tuple, or Row', 'HY000')

But I'm not sure how to get my data into a list, tuple, or row to import into my SQL Server tables

edit I just ended up editing it to a tuple

```
            if yearqtrid.get() == "2019Q3":
            def excelToTuple(hospital, metricKey, lineText, year, quarter, yrQtrRange, num, den, percent):
                for rownum in range(12, sh.nrows):
                    ncdr = tuple(['Hospital','YrQTRid','Metrickey','LineText','Year','Quarter','YrQtrRange','qtrnum','qtrden','qtrpercent','SubGroup'])
                    row_values = sh.row_values(rownum)
                    if isinstance(row_values[metricKey], str) :
                         subgroup = (row_values[metricKey], str)
                    ncdr = (hospitalchosen.get(),yearqtrid.get(),row_values[metricKey],row_values[lineText],year,quarter,yrQtrRange,row_values[num],row_values[den],row_values[percent],subgroup)
                    ncdr_tuple.append(ncdr)
```

Comment: [Cursor.executemany](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Cursor#executemanysql-params-with-fast_executemanyfalse-the-default) expects a sequence of sequences, or a generator of sequences. A list of OrderedDicts isn't compatible.

Comment: If anyone cares i just edited it to make it a tuple